# bundled product tier prices

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, tierprice, ce-1.9.1.2

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.2 and I have bundled products, now I understand that when editing this bundled product you can only insert discount % and not actual price breaks, so when viewing a bundled product on the product view page it shows

> Buy 6 with 5% discount each
>   Buy 20 with 20% discount each
>   Buy 50 with 30% discount each

With simple products you actually get displayed the price including the discount like so

> Buy 12 for £1.07 each and save 5%
>   Buy 50 for £0.96 each and save 15%
>   Buy 100 for £0.90 each and save 20%

Is there any way I can get the bundled products to display the same information with the price for each like the simple products?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, because the bundle price is dynamic. You would need to extend the `Product.Bundle` class from `bundle.js` to update the tier prices dynamically together with the "configured price".

Comment: would you care to elaborate on that answer please